# object required run time error '424'

Tags: excel, userform, vba

i am getting object required run time error in below code at line , i checked sheet names they are correct but still showing same error Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Date & " " & Time

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim username As String
Dim password As String

username = TextBox1.Text
password = TextBox2.Text


Dim info
info = IsWorkBookOpen("D:\TMS_Project\username-password.xlsx")

If info = False Then
Workbooks.Open ("D:\TMS_Project\username-password.xlsx")
End If

Dim x As Integer
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
If Cells(x, 1).Value = username And Cells(x, 2).Value = password Then
MsgBox "Welcome!"
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Date & " " & Time
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"

UserForm1.Hide
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End
Else
x = x + 1
End If

Loop
MsgBox "Please check your username or password!"
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox1.SetFocus


End Sub
```

Comment: it's `Sheet1` the `CodeName`, not necessarily the name of your sheet, right ?

Comment: i think i solved it worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Date & " " & Time

Comment: @shai what you said is also right..i will try in that way

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value`, `Sheet1` is actually the `Worksheet.CodeName` property, read here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel).

While I think you meant to use the worksheet, which name is "**Sheet1**", then you need to use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`.

If you would have defined and set your `Worksheet` object, you would have been able to track it.

I am using the piece of code below, to verify that no one has changed my sheet's name (or deleted it).

```
Option Explicit

' list of worksheet names inside Workbook - easy to modify here later
Const ShtName               As String = "Sheet1"

'====================================================================
Sub VerifySheetObject()

Dim Sht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtName)
On Error GoTo 0
If Sht Is Nothing Then ' in case someone renamed the Sheet (or it doesn't exist)
    MsgBox "Sheet has been renamed, it should be " & Chr(34) & ShtName & Chr(34), vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' your line here
Sht.Range("A1").Value = Date & " " & Time

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Variables for your Sheets use:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Name")
```

If you are refering a lot to worksheets its a must to use, but also makes it much easier to change later on.

Comment: I know that, but when you are not using/opening mutiple workbooks, its not needed.

Comment: Shai Radao and UGP Thanks for your clarification